# ModalPopup_Extender.Hide() Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button, when clicked, a modalpopup with gridview inside it. as below;

```
protected void grdDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      GridViewRow row = grdDetails.SelectedRow;
      //Note: Value of that row's cell must display in A text box (txtBox) on main page
      txtBox.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
      ChargeFilterModalDialogExtender.Hide();
   }
```

After the extender is hide, the value of the cell not displaying in the text box. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Where you have the textbox?

Whether you are using UpdatePanel?, if so define the needed asynchronous postback triggers.